# Is there an antonym for emotionally drifting apart?

Tags: phrase-request

The term "drifting apart" is often used for situations when two people who were close together (usually emotionally) slowly and gradually lose interest in each other, without one specific trauma separating them. It just happens slowly over time.

What is the opposite of this effect? Can "drifting together" be used? I've seen the former term used a lot, but never the latter one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As "drifting" implies a slow process, I would suggest that the opposite of "drifted apart" would be "grew together".

Comment: I think 'drifted' can work just as well with 'together' as it does with 'apart'. It carries an implication of lack of control, awareness or conscious direction, which 'grew' does not.

Comment: There's 'closer' too, aside from the debate on whether 'drifting' is intentional or accidental.

Comment: For "drift", Oxford has "Move passively, aimlessly, or involuntarily into a certain situation or condition."

Comment: @michaelharvey Disagree. "Drift" is directionless, which is fine for parting but doesn't really fit two people becoming closer.

Comment: Wouldn't the opposite imply a ***quickness of coming together***?

Comment: One can drift in a general direction, e.g. towards the shore or away from it. I can imagine a pair of good friends or acquaintances gradually drifting into being a couple, in fact the web is full of references using that terminology.

Comment: Things left to drift tend to be transported by currents, tides etc. They don't always, or maybe often, proceed in a truly random fashion.